# Django project with a table prefix

Tags: mysql, django

I have to run 2 different Django projects which have to share the same database.

They have to share the same database as I need to use Django Models relationships between the 2 projects (Django does not allow relationships across multiple DBs)

Is there a way to have a global **prefix variable** so that Django uses that automatically to generate all tables?
In example:

- project1_auth_user
- project2_auth_user
- ...
- project1_django_migrations
- project2_django_migrations
- ...

Answer (score 4):

So far I haved solved it like this:

I created a file for each project named **table_router.py** which i initialized in the defaults apps.

```
DEFAULT_APPS = [
  'commons.table_router',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'suit',
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

Then in this file I have the following:

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import class_prepared, pre_init

def add_db_prefix(sender, **kwargs):

    ours = sender._meta.managed
    prefix = getattr(settings, "project1_", None)

    if not ours:
        return

    if prefix and not sender._meta.db_table.startswith(prefix):
        sender._meta.db_table = prefix + sender._meta.db_table

pre_init.connect(add_db_prefix)
class_prepared.connect(add_db_prefix)
```

What this does is that all Models which are set to be managed by **project1** in the Model's meta info, the prefix **project1_** is added to table name Django looks for. Doing so, Django reads auth_ and django_ tables with project1_ prefix, otherwise looks for the table name as I have defined in the Models table_name (tables not managed by project1 and are from project2).

Same file for project2 but with project2 prefix.

Comment: We did exactly this and it works like a charm. All managed models get the proper prefix but any existing tables don't change. We did take it a step further and move the prefix definition into settings so it's a bit more obvious and easy to adjust. Sort of a combination of the (above) example and https://github.com/fingul/django-db-prefix

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting question, so I searched in the source (since the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/options/#db-table) only tell, how table names are built, not where this is written)

in django/db/models/options.py I found:

```
if not self.db_table:
    self.db_table = "%s_%s" % (self.app_label, self.model_name)
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
```

maybe this can help you...

I assume, that if you write another prefix in there, it will change the default table names. I also assume, you could subclass your own model class from `models.Model` somewhere in your project, override the `contribute_to_class()` (that's where the above lines are from) in it by the changed version with prefix, and then construct all models from your local class instead of `models.Model`.

But I did not test either...